# ipython3 notebook vertical margin/marker line at 80 characters

Tags: python-3.x, pep8, jupyter-notebook

1. How to make ipython3 notebook show a vertical margin/marker line at 80 characters ?
2. How to get i-bar location in ipython3 notebook ? (e.g. line 30 character 56)

These features assist in writing codes complying with PEP8.
These features are available in Spyder.

Update 1: What I want is a vertical margin/marker line as shown in modified screenshot of the spyder.
The other feature I am looking forward to is identification of location of i-bar. These two features are marked in the attached picture.

A similar solution is also okay.
[Modified screenshot of spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzPxE.png)

update 2: I did not find anything like this on the internet.

update 3: Jupyter Lab has a ruler setting (Sept 2020), details provided in the answer

Comment: Could you show examples of what you have tried, include the code in your question and explain more precisely what you do not achieve ?

Comment: How does this only have 5 votes so far?  Is the intersection between those who care about pep8 and those who use notebooks really that small?

Comment: I am not using notebook anymore. What should I do? What is the standard protocol to be followed in such condition on this forum?

Comment: What are you using now, @Neeraj ?

Comment: @ibarrond: I am using Pycharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `jupyterlab` version 3.3.0 the Advanced Settings Editor (Shortcut: Ctrl+,) has got a nice GUI and a ruler can be set easily under the header "Rulers".

Just click on "Add" and set the wanted number. The changes are applied immediately.

[image: add ruler]

Comment: Note: You'll find there are different options for `Notebooks` and `Text`; Within notebooks there are different options for markdown vs. code cells.

Comment: In version `3.6.4` there **is no** settings category "Rulers" and search for "ruler" leads to NO results (this appears to be a bug since there are in fact many "Ruler" settings). You need to *separately* go to `Notebook` and `Text Editor`, scroll down to "Rulers", click *add ruler*, then specify the character width. The ruler is nearly invisible on low-color-depth monitors and you may need to adjust brightness/contrast to see it. There is no way to adjust the color or style of the rule.

Answer (score 13):

This is Sept 2020. Version 2.2.8 of Jupyter Lab is available.

Answer 1: It provides a facility of a ruler in the Settings > Advanced Settings Editor. Answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/55035981/6646912 gives general guidance on how to edit the settings.
In particular, the following preferences can be included:

```
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
                        "rulers": [80],
                        "wordWrapColumn": 80,
                      },
}
```

Answer 2: Location of i-bar is also available in Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it for a handful of documents there is always:

```
#< ---- 20 char ---->< ---- 20 char --->< ---- 20 char ---><9 char->
```

Which isn't ideal, but much faster than installing extensions and/or changing config files. The last one is 9 to account for the initial comment character.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Jupyter Nbextensions](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). They Provide some (unofficial) community-driven extensions, also the vertical line / ruler like requested. you can find the documentation [on the ruler here](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/ruler/readme.html). I really like to other tools there too, like code prettyfiers or 2to3 converter and execution timer.

As far as I know there is no option to show the column count, but you can show line numbers when pressing `l` while having focus on the cell (focus doesn't equal editing, get the focus with pressing `esc`.

Answer (score 0):

For adding ruler in jupyter notebook, please have a look [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/192). I haven't tried it though. Please let me know if this worked.

For the ibar, line numbers can be achieved - press Esc (or click on the left side of the cell where were see **In [ ]:** to enable the command mode and click letter 'l'.