# Show code line numbers in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter notebook, `cntrl`+ `m` `L` toggles code line numbers in current cell but how to bring the code line numbers in JupyterLab?

Referred a similar issue opened in [github](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4125)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979667/showing-line-numbers-in-ipython-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: @SadmanSobhan That is for notebooks and i already mentioned how to bring the line numbers in the question description. In the documentation for  jupyter lab from here http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/interface.html?highlight=Shortcuts, i couldn't find the shortcut keys for line numbers.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2395 - <kbd>**Shift**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**L**</kbd> toggles line number visibility.

Answer (score 57):

you can turn this on by default by going into Settings --> Advanced Settings Editor:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, you can edit other features as well and easily set them back to default by deleting your 'User Overrides'

Go to *Settings > Advanced configuration* and add:

```json
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "lineNumbers": true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the latest version for people who get to this question later

Comment: Needed to click `JSON settings editor` in the top right of the Advanced Settings Editor to see User Overides

Answer (score 37):

You can go to `View -> Show Line Numbers`:

[image]

which will display line numbers in the notebook:

[image]

Comment: This is great but I don't want to do it every time I open jupyterlab. Why doesn't it persist once I set it?

Answer (score 3):

Late reply, but it'll still help others!

For Windows users, just hit `Shift + L`

Comment: Not just for Windows

Comment: Yeah it works for the Macs too, but I didn't know the keyboard commands for Macs! :)

Comment: works the same in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In your Jupyter Lab, click the chain, <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Line numbers</kbd>. This solution is from this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2395#issuecomment-477164215).

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at this so don't flame me.  But Frank said from View -> Show Line Numbers.  I did this from main JupyterLab window.  I'm using version 3.5.0.

Comment: Please, put it as a comment to Franck and cut it to minimum words (it's hard to navigate it back otherwise). Also, please make it clear if it worked for you.