# JupyterLab: how to display line numbers in **output**

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, line-numbers

### Background

As discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536407/show-code-line-numbers-in-jupyterlab), line numbers can be activated in code cells in a JupyterLab notebook. It shows line numbers in the code cells only. The output cells do not have line numbers.

### Question

How to display line numbers in the output cell?